# Listening to calls (barging) on Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Apart from 555 which gives me random extensions to listen to, is it possible to add another number we can dial that will only listen to a certain extension?

Comment: Please provide the section from your `extensions.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Check dialplan for 555.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_ChanSpy